# Why Jio4GVoice app cannot be implemented for offline use?

Tags: android

For android phone which supports volte, they can directly place call with jio sim without data require, but the phones without volte needs to use Jio4GVoice app or a custom rom which supports volte to make phone calls.

IS there any way , we can implement it for offline use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4th Generation network, which we also know as LTE, was developed forecasting the growing data needs of the future. It was intended to replace wired broadband with wireless devices, a platform for which had already been set with 3G networks.

Hence this time, their focus in the development phase was not Voice, but only Data. To simplify network designs, all communication in & out was to be handled on fully-IP networks, much like the present Internet. This would enable faster, simpler communication than 3G, since all communication is now referred with their node's IP addresses. It was only in the final phases of development that they practically realised, for 4G to completely replace legacy systems, they must find a way to transmit Voice over the network, which they succeeded in, with VoLTE.

Basically, VoLTE speaks for itself, i.e. Voice over LTE.

VoLTE transmits Voice in Data form, much similar to VoIP internet calls we make on WhatsApp or Skype or Google Voice.

This means, you always need to establish a Data network with your respective 4G operator. This is unlike the system established in 2G/3G networks, where it would establish data networks only when you needed to surf the internet. Those were based on two way systems, different for Voice & Data.

4G transmits both Voice & Data simultaneously over the same Data pipeline, so you have the right to only be charged in Data you consume & not Minutes you talk. Which is the reason why Jio does not charge you separately for calls. The bandwidth required to transmit Voice is very small, (most calls usually fall in the range of KBs, in standard plan you get 1GB per day) & so Jio deducts the data used for Voice from your Data balance.

Since everything is data, you need to establish the data connection on your 4G smartphone or JioFi router to make calls. Hence Jio4GVoice app cannot function without a data connection.

I've seen in various VoLTE enabled smartphones, they still give you a Data Toggle/Switch to turn on/off data so that you can conserve some when not in use. It does not physically terminate data communication with the network, since it is the only connection. Rather, it just isolates all apps on your system from accessing the internet, and only the Dialer is given access to continue to make & receive 4G VoLTE calls.

Hope I've managed to solve all your curiosities.

Comment: means you are saying , in volte smartphones when we make call ,(when data is off) It automatically enables data only for dialer and make call.

Comment: What I'm saying is, data is never disabled when you toggle data off in VoLTE smartphones, only that other apps are told by Android that data is off, while in reality it is still connected. Just that only Dialer gets to access it to receive VoLTE calls, which is as the user expects it to be and is pretty neat feature.

Comment: In your case, I assume from your original question you have a non-VoLTE 4G device. So you need Jio4GVoice app to make calls. Here, we are not making any calls from the Android system dialer. Think of Jio4GVoice as just another internet based VoIP calls app, like Hangouts or WhatsApp, because that's what it is. It just communicates using your phone's 4G data. So in this case, the smart Android functionality we talked about in the above paragraph is not available. So, if you turn data off, it is actually off. So now you can't make or receive your Jio calls unless data is turned on.